# What's the algorithm to assign people their most preferred value based on a list of their top choices?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, ranking

Let's say users input their top three (or N) preferred baseball positions:

```
// first element of each list being most preferred
userA = ["backcatcher", "center field", "short stop"];
userB = ["pitcher", "backcatcher", "center field"];
userC = ["pitcher", "center field", "short stop"];
userD = ["short stop", "backcatcher", "pitcher"];
...

users = [userA, userB, userC, userD ...];
```

What's the algorithm to assign each user the most preferred position as possible?

I know there must be some name for this problem and the solution, but I've looked online a bunch and haven't quite found it.

It's similar to a [Borda count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_count) and the [Condorcet method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method) but that takes in a users list of preferences and determines how preferred each selection is total, not by each user.

The closest I've found is [the stable marriage problem](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem), which is similar, but requires two sets of preferred lists, ie. the position "short stop" would also list which users it most wanted to play it.

Does anyone know what this problem is called? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many users? This can get very complicated very quickly.

Comment: @jsve At the moment I have 12, but I'm more interested in a general algorithm for N people if at all possible.

Comment: What's your cost model? The optimal algorithm will depend on how you evaluate how "good" a particular assignment is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). You could use, for instance, the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

You just need to come up with a way to turn the user/player preferences into costs. Perhaps when a person gets their first choice, the cost is -3, second choice is -2, third choice is -1, etc. How you do that depends on the nature of your problem. How you view the various trade offs ends up encoded in the costs you give the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! As soon as I knew the name I could find a solution. And here's a useful tool to solve it automatically: https://www.easycalculation.com/operations-research/work-assignment.php